# Submit form and change page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I'm trying to submit a form, open a new page that will receive the datas, while the current page would go back to the index.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
<form method="post" action="newpage.php" target="_blank" onsubmit="location.replace('index.php')">
//inputs
<input type=image src="image.jpg" alt="Send" value=submit />
</form>
```

So what I want it to do is open newpage.php in a new tab, and open index.php in the current tab, but it doesn't seem to work that way.
I also tried adding

```
onclick="location.replace('index.php')
```

to my submit input, but it didn't work either.

Is there a way to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to use Ajax.

Comment: I've never used Ajax at all, is there a simple way to do it for a beginner ?

Comment: Have a look at what Billy posted below. That looks about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//If you want to use Ajax + jQuery:

var fromData = $(#formID).serialize(); // your form's data
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "newpage.php",
  data: fromData //sends the data to the new page.
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    window.location.href = 'index.php' // redirects the page when finished.
});
```

Comment: As I said in another comment, I've never used Ajax before. Am I supposed to use this between <script> tags in a function that I'll call when clicking my button?

Comment: Yes, the code i wrote you need to use in a function within the <script> tag or in your JS file.
But you also have to include jQuery source in your file.
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
Call the function with onclick='functionName()' on the button

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you should place the redirection in `newpage.php` (to `index.php`)

Explanation: the `onsubmit` event is fired when the submit button is clicked, before the page unloaded, after that the action page is loaded. Note: if `onsubmit` returns false, the submition is cancelled.

because your page was unloaded, it obviously cannot force any redirections. You should redirect from the newly loaded action page.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp